# How do I set parent variable and access it from child in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to switch to OOP way of programming in PHP. I'm running into the issues with multiple children and one single parent classes.

In my parent's construct method I include a child class file with include() method and then create a variable referencing the child class like so:

```
class App {
    function __construct() {
        include_once('childClass.php');
        $this->childvar = new childClass;

        include_once('childClass2.php');
        $this->childvar2 = new childClass2;
    }
}
```

And my child classes are as follows:

```
class childClass extends App {
    var test = 1;

    function __construct() {

    }
}

class childClass2 extends App {
    function __construct() {
        echo $this->childvar->test;
    }
}
```

When I try to access a childClass vriable from childClass2 I get an error

> Undefined property: childClass2::$test

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think there is a lot wrong here. Note that by each creation of one of the child classes you create (via the baseclass App) two more childClass instances..infinitely. What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the constructor of `App` in `childClass2` make sure you call `parent::__construct();` first.

```
class childClass2 extends App {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->childvar->test;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that as it is this will create an infinite loop.

---

In general it is not common to see a `new` call in a constructor. Any dependencies should be passed in. This incidentally also deals with the infinite loop. Your current design has more problems though.

```
class App {
    function __construct($child1, $child2) {
        $this->child1 = $child1;
        $this->child2 = $child2;
    }
}
class childClass extends App {
    var test = 1;

    function __construct($child1, $child2) {
        parent::__construct($child1, $child2);
    }
}

class childClass2 extends App {
    function __construct($child1, $child2) {
        parent::__construct($child1, $child2);
        echo $this->childvar->test; // error childvar is null
    }
}

$app = new App(new childClass(null, null), new childClass2(null, null));
```

Comment: How do I avoid the infinite loop in this case? I hate declaring all properties in the parent class before the construct method.

Comment: I added some more. It's currently not possible to create `childClass2` because it always needs another child, and that child needs another child and so on..

Comment: Alright, I'm trying to get it but I can't. WHat I'm trying to do is to keep as less code in index.php as possible. From index.php I'm trying to include App.php class file, and from there just include all other classes like Config, Content, Template, User, Database etc... Now, in Database I need to have access to Config, as Config contains database connection variables.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to keep passing `new ClassName` into App class for each dependent class, there might be too many of them.

Comment: You can avoid having to do manual includes with  autoloading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php If you have many dependencies then so be it. You have to declare them sometime, better do it upfront so your code remains testable.

Comment: Halcyon, what I like in PHP is the ability to declare/unset variables at any moment. I don't want to go back to main App class to add each new variable or remove an old not anymore needed one. Besides, the App class can have properties and I need those properties accessible from any child class at any moment, without them being declared in the parent class. So I can declare User class property from Content class when user is logged in, whereas that property is not necessary if user is not logged in. I feel like OOP only complicates everything now.

Comment: You need to think more in an OOP mind. There is not always a `User` object, true, but there is always an `Authentication` object, either in the form of `unauthenticated` or `authenticated`. When the state is `authenticated` there _may_ be a `User` object depending on the type of authentication; you might also have jobs that have some kind of API key authentication. Perhaps more than OOP, think about _dependency injection_. DI allows you to make your code more modular and testable.

Comment: Yes, so my understanding of OOP tells me that object `App` can have properties `user` and `content`: `App->user`, `App->content`. And child object `User` can as well have a property `authenticated`: `User->authenticated`. Now why can't I access `App->user->authenticated` from `App->content`, which is the `Content` class? Inside `Content` - `$this->user->authenticated` will fail!

Comment: I'm not sure what your classes currently look like but Symfony has a very decomposition: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html Their model starts with a `Request` and builds up from there. Authentication happens somewhere in the controller.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symphony and neither I'm using it in my application. I provided my class examples in the description of the question. childClass can be considered my Config and childClass2 can be considered my Database. So in Database I need to access Config::test. How do I do that?

Comment: So long as they extend from `App` that is going to be very problematic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59952/discussion-between-piero-and-halcyon).